# Can't download file inside nupckg

Tags: jfrog-cli

I have a nuspec file inside a nuget package stored in artifactory.
In Artifact Repository Browser I'm able to view and download this nuspec file.
However I can't download it from jfrog.exe.

I've tried

```
jfrog.exe rt dl foldername/packagename.nupkg!/filename.nuspec
```

and I get nothing.

So far my only solution is to download the entire package

```
jfrog.exe rt dl foldername/packagename.nupkg
```

and then unzip it to extract filename.nuspec

Do you have a better suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your observation is correct. CLI is not yet supported to download the files under a wrapped file like ZIP/nupkg files.
Alternativly, you can use REST API

```
curl -uadmin:password -O "http://localhostL8082/artifactory/nuget-local/entityframework.6.2.0.nupkg\!/EntityFramework.nuspec"
```

Also, make sure to add a backward slash (\) before the special character (!) as an escape.

You may raise an improvement request on https://github.com/jfrog/jfrog-cli/issues